# Which point in time does time() measure, relative to execution of a statement it's in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is not about algorithms or fixing an error in code. I just want to make it clear how tracking time works. For example, there's line:

```
x = my_func(4, 2) * time()
```

The line run at 3.0 second and `my_func(4, 2)` takes 0.5 seconds to return the result.

The question is when does time() start tracking time? At 3.0 second, when the line runs? Or at 3.5, after my_func(4, 2) is calculated?

Comment: Why would you expect `time()` to behave differently than *any other function*? It's not some special "tracking" feature; it's just a function that returns the time of its invocation, so the order-of-operations that applies to everything else also applies to determining when that invocation happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most operators, the operands of the "*" operator are evaluated in left-to-right order. `my_func` will finish executing before `time` starts executing. You can test this empirically by using functions that print to stdout as a side-effect, for example:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     print(x)
...     return 0
...
>>> x = f("1st") * f("2nd")
1st
2nd
```

Incidentally, if you're trying to track the runtime of `my_func`, doing `my_func(4, 2) * time()` is not a very practical way of doing that. `time.time()` returns the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, so calling it once won't tell you anything about the length of your program unless you started running it on January 1 1970. A more conventional approach would be to do `start_time = time.time()` at the beginning of your program, then `end_time = time.time()` at the end, and then subtract the two.

Or you could use the `timeit` module, which is specifically designed for that kind of benchmarking.

Comment: an example that might help the OP: `x = print('1st') or print('2nd')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I disagree. The OP is using `*` not the `or` operator.

Comment: The general idea of "as an illustrative example, provide operands that have observable side-effects" is sound, so I integrated that into my post while still using `*`.